# Не дали знак "некромант"

Tags: поддержка, знаки

Судя по описанию - условия выполнил, получил 10 балов за ответ на вопрос старше 60 дней, а знака в профиле нету.
Сам ответ 
[Delphi. Модальное окно не блокируют главную форму](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/670683/delphi-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83/882255#882255)

Comment: Там неточность в переводе. Нужно 5 голосов за ответ, не 5 баллов репутации :(

Comment: Очень жаль =) но будем попробовать и 5 голосов набрать =) 
Спасибо за ответ =)) и за голос =))))

Comment: И это не метка, а знак. А метки есть только у вопросов.

Comment: Согласен =) думал непонятно о чем =) поправил в заголовке и в теле вопроса.

Comment: Вроде так и написано в описании знака: "Ответить на вопрос старше 60 дней и набрать при этом как минимум 5 баллов. Знак можно получать многократно." Не понял, где про 10 баллов? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer

Comment: Вот о том и речь
" как минимум 5 баллов", я же набрал 10, вроде 10>5, поэтому и возник вопрос, но как уже выше сказали, глюки перевода, 5 голосов надо а не 5 баллов.

Comment: Могу предположить, что знаки назначаются не мгновенно, а в ближайшую полночь по Гринвичу (т. е. в три часа ночи по Москве). Скорее всего знак будет назначен завтра.